# MSE/MAE for Decision Tree Python scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I tried to calculate the MSE/MAE of predicted Y from a decision tree using the functions from: sklearn.metrics.

But when I compare the results with my anayltical formulas they are different. Is there a reason for this because when I compare them for regression outputs they are the same?

```
DT=DecisionTreeRegressor()

yy_pred2_DT=cross_val_predict(DT, XX,yy,cv=5)

np.mean((yy-yy_pred2_DT)**2) = 92469834.194810331

mean_squared_error(yy,yy_pred2_DT)= 47674131.176100627
```

Comment: Show a more complete code and use syntax-highlighting.

Comment: @Dion see my edit on how to format your code for better readability.

Comment: We are missing information. Please include minimal data to reproduce the example : for toy 1D arrays a and a I get equal values for np.mean((a -- b)) ** 2 and mean_squared_error(a, b)

Comment: Sorry about the format but the problem was that output of cross_val_predict was (n,) and needed to reshape it to (n,1)